# Keep columns in the same row until header result is different using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4

I would like to display as shown below, but I can't get to anything that will display addresses that belongs to a certain state, side by side in the same row, until the states changes.

```
<h1>State1</h1>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h2>City1</h2>
      <p>Address1</p>
   </div>
```

***if next address is in the same state:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h2>City2</h2>
      <p>Address2</p>
   </div>
</div><!-- ROW -->

    <hr>
```

***addresses will be in the same row until state is different, then close the div.

**if next address is NOT in the same state

```
<h1>State2</h1>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h2>City3</h2>
      <p>Address3</p>
   </div>
...
</div> <!-- ROW -->
```

I'm using:

```
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM places";
        $select_all_places = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $current_state = '';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_places)){
            $p_state = $row['p_state'];
            $p_city = $row['p_city'];
            $p_address = $row['p_address'];

        ?>
            <?php if($current_state != $p_state): ?>
                <h1><?php echo $p_state; ?></h1>
                <?php $current_state = $p_state; ?>
<div class="row">
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="col-sm-3">
               <h2><?php echo $p_city; ?></h2>
               <p><?php echo $p_address; ?></p>
            </div>
</div>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I advice you to also post table structure and example data.. See  [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and make as expected results the html code you would expect with the example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order addresses by state, to make sure that you list all of one state and only then go to another state addresses.

This code will do it.

```
<?php
    $select_all_places = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM places ORDER BY p_state ASC");
    $current_state = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_places))
    {
        if($current_state != $row['p_state'])
        {
            if($current_state!='')
            {
                echo'</div>';
            }
            $current_state = $row['p_state'];
            echo '<h1>'.$row['p_state'].'</h1><div class="row">';
        }
        echo'<div class="col-sm-3"><h2>'.$row['p_city'].'</h2><p>'.$row['p_address'].'</p></div>';
    }
?>
```

It takes sorted addresses from database.

Loop trough them and show H1 header then state changes.

If there was a state list earlier, closes div element of previous state.

Comment: It worked well, the only thing I had to do was to substitute the $row.. for the variables, that way it worked!